# Using Database Info as a Constant in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, constants

I don't exactly know how to word this, so I am going to try my best at it. I am trying to make a constant out of a certain column within my database. What is it is a site where you can make reservations to certain events being held. Within the database there is a column for the maximum number of seats(num_seats) at the specific venue. On the website, it shows the max number of seat left/available(number subtracts when someone reserves a seat(s)). What I am trying to do, is at a certain number have the availability go from Available to Limited to None. The "None" part is easy, what I am looking for is the Limited. I want it to change to "Limited" when only about 1/3 of the venue is available.

Now, when the owner enters the number of seats(we'll say 100), the database populates with 100, so 1/3 would be roughly 34. My problem is, when a person register, the number goes down, so 99 = 33, 90 = 31, 80 = 26. It will always change, so if I say:

```
if($num_seats < $row['num_seats'] / .33) {
    echo "Limited";
}
```

This will never be true since it always changes. My question(sorry for being "long-winded") is, is there of making the number a constant within my php code, or will it just be easier to add a new column to the database and have one named max_num_seats and the other name seats_avail?

Thanks in advanced...

Comment: Don't you already have a column _seats_avail_? Or how do you retrieve the current number of available seats?

Comment: Absolutely store a separate column for the maximum number possible.

Comment: I think your math it's wrong.... `$row['num_seats'] / .33` it's not 1/3 of the all the seats.... try wtih `$row['num_seats'] / 3` or if you preffer `$row['num_seats'] * .33`

Comment: silfire, my column num_seats is what I am using for seats_avail. Nothing stores the initial number of seats. Michael Berkowski, figured that would be the best bet. Thanks. jcho360, looking at my math, you are totally correct. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use two tables: one for the 'owner' where the total number of seats is stored and another for the reservations. Then do your join/select and figure out what to display.